# how to fetch mysql data in specific order?

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

i have mysql data

| name (varcha 25) | role (varcha 25) | street (varcha 25) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | abc |
| B | 1 | def |
| C | 2 | abc |
| D | 1 | ghi |

that i try to fetch data in specific order: first- role ASC and name ASC then same street like this result:

| name | role | street |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | abc |
| C | 2 | abc |
| B | 1 | def |
| D | 1 | ghi |

i try using "order by role ASC, street ASC" but it give me this result:

| name | role | street |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | abc |
| B | 1 | def |
| D | 1 | ghi |
| C | 2 | abc |

i also try using two nest query(this method is working but it slower)

```
$row = "Select * from data group by street order by role"
"Select * from data where name != "$row[name]" order by street"
```

that i try to fetch data in specific order: first- role ASC and name ASC then same street like this result:

| name | role | street |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | abc |
| C | 2 | abc |
| B | 1 | def |
| D | 1 | ghi |

Comment: If that last data set is your desired result, that would be `ORDER BY street ASC, role ASC, name ASC`

Comment: if i do your way, then street name go first, if i dont have data "A" then result will be "C B D" which is incorrect, i want role go first. what i try to do is simple state "first find important people - role 1, then same street (same street dont care about the role)"

Comment: is `name` indexed? You should use prepared statements. Can you add schema to question please? This also isn't really a PHP question.

Comment: is schema and name indexed important?

Comment: You said you want role first, then street, but the desired data set shown is ordered by street and then role.  Please update your desired data set.

Comment: my desired data set is role then street A 1 - C 2 - B 1 - D 1, A role 1 then C same street, then B role 1 then C role 1

Comment: If you don't index the `name` the query executes slower because it needs to figure it out on the fly. A `schema` is the structure of your table.

Comment: i do have all column index all column is varcha(25)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, join the table to itself - for each row look for any others in the same street with a lower role number.  If there is another row with a lower role number, use that role number to sort, otherwise use the original row's role number.  Finally order by street (to bring similar records together) and the original role number

```
SELECT DISTINCT d1.name, d1.role, d1.street
FROM data d1
LEFT JOIN data d2 on d1.street = d2.street AND d1.name <> d2.name AND d2.role < d1.role
ORDER BY IFNULL(d2.role, d1.role), d1.street, d1.role
```